# How can I achieve UnrealEd's per-face texturing in Blender 2.6?

Tags: textures, blender, udk

Using UnrealEd I can create geometry and assign a material to each face of that geometry. Each face can have its own UV settings. How can I achieve the same functionality using Blender?

I've seen the "Texture Face" option mentioned but that seems to be gone in Blender 2.59+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to select the face(s) in editmode and then in the Properties window under Materials, click Assign to apply the mat you choose from the list.
See 
http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/learning-multiple-materials-textures-images.php